# Pass multiple values to child component as props in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a parent component like this

```
    export default class Parent extends Component{
    .....
    render() {
        let props = {
            lat: this.state.lat,
            long: this.state.long
        }

        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Child props = {this.props}/>
            </View>
        )
      }
    }
```

And when I tried to pass 2 lat & long values to a component like this:

```
export default class Child extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return (
        <View>
            <Text>{"Longitude: " + this.props.long}</Text>
            <Text>{"Latitude: " + this.props.lat}</Text>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I got a screen like:

```
Longitude: undefined
Latitude: undefined
```

So which mistakes did I make in this case?

Comment: `<Child lat={this.state.lat} long={this.state.long} />` (I wouldn't create a `props` variable in your render method, that's only going to be confusing)

Comment: thank you. it worked ^^^^^^